# jenkins on kubernetes - 1 agent can connect

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, devops

I have installed jenkins on kubernetes (EKS). It's been running for over a year now. i'v noticed that when you run parallell jobs, it just runs one job at a time. I cannot remember if it ever ran two jobs in parallel.

The pod works after the first one finishes.
[image]
[image]
Second jobs logs that get stuck :

jenkins-master logs:

```
    2023-02-02 09:14:00.995+0000 [id=962] INFO hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner#update: devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg provisioning successfully completed. We have now 3 computer(s)
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:14:22.133+0000 [id=961] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Created Pod: kubernetes jenkins/devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-2-master-18-9vk02-n88q-qxlv5
    [jenkins-0][config-reload] [2023-02-02 09:14:22] Working on ADDED configmap jenkins/jenkins-jenkins-jcasc-config
    [jenkins-0][config-reload] [2023-02-02 09:14:22] Contents of jcasc-default-config.yaml haven't changed. Not overwriting existing file
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:14:24.818+0000 [id=961] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Pod is running: kubernetes jenkins/devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-2-master-18-9vk02-n88q-qxlv5
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:14:24.942+0000 [id=982] INFO h.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler#run: Accepted JNLP4-connect connection #8 from /10.20.41.123:54556
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:14:31.008+0000 [id=974] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Created Pod: kubernetes jenkins/devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:14:33.287+0000 [id=974] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Pod is running: kubernetes jenkins/devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:14:43.168+0000 [id=995] INFO o.c.j.p.k.p.ContainerExecDecorator$1#doLaunch: Created process inside pod: [devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-2-master-18-9vk02-n88q-qxlv5], container: [awsterraform][384 ms]
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:15:03.536+0000 [id=974] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (30/1,000): devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:15:19.081+0000 [id=1023] INFO o.c.j.p.k.p.ContainerExecDecorator$1#doLaunch: Created process inside pod: [devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-2-master-18-9vk02-n88q-qxlv5], container: [awsterraform][312 ms]
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:15:21.728+0000 [id=1027] INFO o.c.j.p.k.p.ContainerExecDecorator$1#doLaunch: Created process inside pod: [devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-2-master-18-9vk02-n88q-qxlv5], container: [awsterraform][303 ms]
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:15:25.390+0000 [id=996] INFO o.c.j.p.k.p.ContainerExecDecorator$1#doLaunch: Created process inside pod: [devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-2-master-18-9vk02-n88q-qxlv5], container: [awsterraform][323 ms]
    [jenkins-0][config-reload] [2023-02-02 09:15:27] Working on ADDED configmap jenkins/jenkins-jenkins-jcasc-config
    [jenkins-0][config-reload] [2023-02-02 09:15:27] Contents of jcasc-default-config.yaml haven't changed. Not overwriting existing file
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:15:33.771+0000 [id=974] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (60/1,000): devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:15:51.476+0000 [id=994] INFO o.c.j.p.k.p.ContainerExecDecorator$1#doLaunch: Created process inside pod: [devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-2-master-18-9vk02-n88q-qxlv5], container: [awsterraform][285 ms]
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:16:04.013+0000 [id=974] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (90/1,000): devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg
    [jenkins-0][config-reload] [2023-02-02 09:16:32] Working on ADDED configmap jenkins/jenkins-jenkins-jcasc-config
    [jenkins-0][config-reload] [2023-02-02 09:16:32] Contents of jcasc-default-config.yaml haven't changed. Not overwriting existing file
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:16:34.209+0000 [id=974] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (120/1,000): devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg
    [jenkins-0][jenkins] 2023-02-02 09:17:04.399+0000 [id=974] INFO o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (150/1,000): devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg

iac-prod-eu-west-1-1-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg (stuck agent) 


Feb 02, 2023 9:14:32 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: devops-iac-prod-eu-west-1-nyxgib-master-28-71sh2-hhnlk-46vsg
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 4.11
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://jenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:80/]
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting TCP connection tunneling is enabled. Skipping the TCP Agent Listener Port availability check
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
 Agent address: jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local
 Agent port: 50000
 Identity: fe:1f:fb:8a:cf:ca:ad:1e:55:a3:a0:b1:94:5a:36:2b
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Feb 02, 2023 9:14:33 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000
Feb 02, 2023 9:16:53 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000
 at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:248)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.connectTcp(Engine.java:880)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:757)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:540)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
 at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:206)
 ... 3 more

Feb 02, 2023 9:19:13 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000 (retrying:3)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000
 at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:248)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.connectTcp(Engine.java:880)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:757)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:540)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
 at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:206)
 ... 3 more
```